# How to correlate values in the same column by group using groups in another column

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataset that looks like this in R:

```
Species      Abundance  Site
Orange       2          1
Potato       3          1
Strawberry   1          1
Tomato       1          1
Blackberry   5          2
Potato       4          2
Prickly Pear 3          2
Apple        4          3
Orange       3          3
Strawberry   2          3
Tomato       5          3
Apple        4          4
Orange       5          4
Mango        5          4
Pineapple    3          4
Tomato       1          4
```

What I am interested in is the correlations between each species across sites. E.g. do apple and orange usually occur together? Do prickly pear and mango rarely occur together? I'm not too sure how to go about this. When a species doesn't occur at a site it can be assumed to have a 0 at that site however my dataset does not have rows where a species was not detected at a site.

How can I look at correlations between different species across sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
library(reshape)

new <- cast(mydata, Site ~ Species, value='ABUNDANCE', fun.aggregate = sum)
cor(new)
```